# Is my logic wrong

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

On a math.stackechange this question was asked,

> Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$; $f(1)=1$; and $f(\sqrt 2)=3$?

I solved it as per this,

First of all we start by taking $x,y=0$
$$f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$$
$$f(0)=0\cdots (1)$$

> Now
>   $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
>   $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x)+f(h)-f(x)}{h}$$
>   $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$$
>   Now as $f(0)=0$ we can apply the L'Hospital rule,
>   $$f'(x)=f'(0)$$

Now as f'(0) is const,
Integrating both the sides,
$$\int_{0}^{x} f'(x)dx=\int_{0}^{x} f'(0)dx$$
$$f(x)-f(0)=f'(0)x$$
$$f(x)=f'(0)x$$

> Now if,
>   $$f(1)=f'(0)=1$$ 
>   It cannot be that,
>   $$f(\sqrt{2})=f'(0)\sqrt{2}=3$$
>   $$f'(0)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$$
>
> But one of the answer says such function does exist, where did I go wrong?

Link:$\ref{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428719/does-there-exist-a-function-f-mathbbr→-mathbbr-such-that-fxy-fxfy/2428750#2428750}{ here}$

> And if f is non-differentiable, how do we solve these equations?

And can someone name a function if $f$ is non-úmgcos table and satisfies the above conditions?

Comment: You assume $f$ is differentiable, without justification.

Comment: How can we solve this for non-differentiable functions then??

Comment: Indirectly, as per the answer to your other posting of this question. Look at the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation . The nonlinear solutions are ugly: unbounded, discontinous, non measurable, and solutions cannot really be exhibited explicitly.

Comment: Ok so my proof will be valid only if f is differentiable?

Comment: I'm sorry: I confused you with lithobatiks.

Comment: I did not look closely at your argument, but I believe if you assume $f$ obeys $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, and that $f$ is differentiable at zero, then an argument like yours will deliver $f(x)=ax$ for some $a$.

Comment: So you want to say $f'(0)$ might be not defined?

Comment: But if i take f'(0) RHD and LHD  we will get the same answer, so f'(0) must exist?

Comment: @neonpokharkar See [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation) for a discussion of additive functions that are not differentiable (and not linear).

Comment: Don't forget your differentials ($dx$, $dy$, $d\theta$, etc.) when you integrate.

Comment: From your reference, if f(x) is not differentiable, then it must me not differentiable at all the points?

Comment: What about the answer in answer section?

Comment: Fallacious.  The inference "then you can prove" is obviously not true: the linear solution $f(x)=0 \forall x$ is a counterexample to that step.  Fourth line a non-sequitur.

Comment: Why accept a wrong answer?

Comment: And why keep it accepted after everybody, its author included, signalled to you that it is incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

The question the OP refers to is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428719/does-there-exist-a-function-f-mathbbr%E2%86%92-mathbbr-such-that-fxy-fxfy), which has a concise answer by Robert Israel, which the OP and the "answerer" Isham evidently do not understand.  The fact that [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) has nonlinear  solutions has been known for more than a century. (It's a 1905 result of G. Hamel.)  All solutions are $\mathbb Q$-linear functions on  $\mathbb R$, regarding the latter as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.  Given a Hamel basis for $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ one can construct $f$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(\sqrt 2)=3$, as Israel shows.  But not all $\mathbb Q$-linear functions on $\mathbb R$ are $\mathbb R$- linear, which infuriates the naive.  Adding to the infuriating nature of the problem is the fact that there seems to be no easy way to construct and exhibit Hamel bases.  But: the original poster's "proof" is fallacious, as is Isham's "answer".